# How to diagnose a BSOD that prevents booting in Windows 8?

Tags: windows, windows-8, bsod

our computer recently started BSOD'ing before booting to the login screen. It then restarts, trys to fix itself, and fails. I have access to command prompt from there, along with other options like 'Reset' and 'Refresh'.

How can I use command prompt to get the error code and other information required to diagnose a BSOD?

Comment: Try booting into safe mode. After the POST, press F8 until you get the boot menu.

Comment: copy the dmp files from C:\Windows\Minidump via cmd.exe to an external drive and upload them. I'll try to look at them with Windbg. Maybe this helps to see which issue you have.